# Function doesn't return all results from 'for' loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I've made a simple function to print out a times table chart depending on the number you decide to run with. The problem I'm having due to my basic understanding of the language is why it only returns the first loop and nothing else.

```
def timestables(number):
  for a in range(1, number+1):
    b = a*a
    c = a
    return (str(c) + " * " + str(c) + " = " + str(b))

print(timestables(5))
```

I get the answer ..

```
1 * 1 = 1
```

I've tried to rectify this issue by using print instead of return but this ultimately results with a None appearing as well.

```
def timestables(number):
  for a in range(1, number+1):
    b = a*a
    c = a
    print (str(c) + " * " + str(c) + " = " + str(b))

print(timestables(5))
```

I get the answer ..

```
1 * 1 = 1
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 3 = 9
4 * 4 = 16
5 * 5 = 25
None
```

How can I return all given results from the for loop to avoid a None error?

Comment: indentation is significant in python. please fix the indentation in your post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're `return`ing inside the `for` loop - and functions stop execution immediately once they hit a `return` statement.

To work around this, you can use a list to store those values, and then return that list.

```
def timestables(number):
    lst = []
    for a in range(1, number+1):
        b = a*a
        c = a
        lst.append(str(c) + " * " + str(c) + " = " + str(b))
    return lst
```

As a side note, you should use [*string formatting*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) to build the string, like so.

```
lst.append('{a} * {a} = {b}'.format(a=a, b=a*a))
```

Now we can get rid of all those intermediate variables (`b` and `c`), and we can use a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead.

```
def timestables(number):
    return ['{a} * {a} = {b}'.format(a=a, b=a*a) for a in range(1, number+1)]
```

If you don't want the function to return a list, but a multi-line string, you can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
def timestables(number):
    return '\n'.join('{a} * {a} = {b}'.format(a=a, b=a*a) for a in range(1, number+1))
```

Now we can test the function:

```
>>> print(timestables(5))
1 * 1 = 1
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 3 = 9
4 * 4 = 16
5 * 5 = 25
```

Comment: Would be better with `yield` or a generator expression than building a list, but +1 for explaining *why* `return` doesn't do what the OP expects.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, it looks much cleaner!! I'm trying to figure out how to get this desired result by only using a `print` function however.

Answer (score 16):

[`yield`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) them.

```
def timestables(number):
  for a in range(1, number+1):
    yield '%s + %s = %s' % (a, a, a*a )

for x in timestables(5):
  print x
```

This turns your function into a generator function, and you need to iterate over the results, i.e. the result is not a list, but an iterable.

If you need a list, the simplest is to explicitly create one:

```
res = list(timestables(5))
```

But again, if you don't, you don't.

IMHO, this is the most pythonic way.

Comment: Was just typing this, you beat me to it.

Comment: ...except that using string formatting would make it *more* pythonic (a lot simpler as well)

Comment: @Volatility, yes I agree. except that this question is about the loop, not the strings...

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array:

```
def timestables(number):
    out = []
    for a in range(1, number+1):
        b = a*a
        c = a
        out.append( str(c) + " * " + str(c) + " = " + str(b))

    return out
print(timestables(5))
```

Comment: I wish to retain the current format rather than convert it into a list. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: You can always join the list to convert it to string `'\n'.join(out)`